# Issue with red hues in image processing with image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image (620x1024), that I want to turn into a same sized image of equally luminous red.  What do?

Comment: Please shw us What you have tried?

Comment: `load('treefire64-wildfires_com.jpeg')
mypicture = treefire64-wildfires_com.image;
mypicture(mypicture('red')).isequal(true);
mypicture(mypicture('red'==false)) = NaN;
plot(mypicture, 'true');`

Comment: It if helps, this is the error I'm getting: `Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the type of thing you're looking for?

```
function h = redifyImage(fname, luminosity)
    img = imread(fname);
    img(:,:,2:3) = 0;
    img(:,:,1) = luminosity;
    h = image(img);
end
```